# Postgresql - LDAP Authentication against Active Directory (AD) - trouble from linux server while ok from windows server

Tags: postgresql, authentication, active-directory, ldap, postgresql-9.4

**EDIT**

I put the same pg_hba rule on the postgresql installed on my WINDOWS laptop, and it works... so I changed titled : how can I make my linux server work to authenticate users with AD, like the windows Pg server does ?

**/ EDIT**

I need to perform authentication of postgresql db users with our Active Directory servers. I've tested lots of configurations but so far, I couldn't find why postgresql users can't be authenticated with this authentication methode.

LDAP : Active Directory / Postgresql : Postgresql 9.4

Here is the pg_hba rule I use :

```
host myDB myUser localhost ldap ldapserver="192.168.10.1" ldapbasedn="DC=companygroup,DC=priv" ldapbinddn="cn=LDAP - Lecture,ou=Users,ou=Specials Objects,dc=companygroup,dc=priv" ldapbindpasswd="ldapPassWord" ldapsearchattribute="sAMAccountName"
```

When logging with 'myUser' with the correct password for this user, I have the following logs in postgresql log file :

```
2015-11-18 10:01:50 CET [25991-1] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG: 00000: connection received: host=127.0.0.1 port=39074
2015-11-18 10:01:50 CET [25991-2] [unknown]@[unknown] LOCATION: BackendInitialize, postmaster.c:4003
2015-11-18 10:01:50 CET [25991-3] myUser@myDB LOG: 00000: could not search LDAP for filter "(sAMAccountName=myUser)" on server "192.168.10.1": Operations error
2015-11-18 10:01:50 CET [25991-4] myUser@myDB LOCATION: CheckLDAPAuth, auth.c:2030
2015-11-18 10:01:50 CET [25991-5] myUser@myDB FATAL: 28000: LDAP authentication failed for user "myUser"
2015-11-18 10:01:50 CET [25991-6] myUser@myDB DETAIL: Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 104: "host myDB myUser localhost ldap ldapserver="192.168.10.1" ldapbasedn="DC=companygroup,DC=priv" ldapbinddn="cn=LDAP - Lecture,ou=Users,ou=Specials Objects,dc=companygroup,dc=priv" ldapbindpasswd="ldapPassWord" ldapsearchattribute="sAMAccountName"
```

I saw that if I change somehow  ldapbinddn or ldapbindpasswd, I have another error like 'couldn't perform initial LDAP bind for ldapbinddn "...".   so these parameters should be ok.

"Operations error" was no very detailed, so I tcpdump the authentication process and here is what I found. It seems that Postgres perform two queries :

- First to search the user via the search attribute. This action seems OK because in the response of Active Directory, I saw information tied to my user.
- Then another query is performed. On this one, the real message from the LDAP Active directory server is :

  LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0 , v1db1

On this second query, I see that PG seem to change slightly the base search with 
 "DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=companygroup,dc=priv" instead of "DC=companygroup,DC=priv"

(I saw it in the tcp trace :

```
LDAPMessage searchRequest(3) "DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=companygroup,dc=priv" wholeSubtree ...
```

)

When I tried a research thanks to windows soft "ldapbrowser", I was abled to find my account with a simple filter (sAMAccountName=myUser), with the searchDN DC=companygroup,DC=priv

Is my understanding correct ? is it possible that the search is not successful just because of the basedn that is maybe changed ? or do I miss something else ?

Comment: It seems you can't have an ldapbasedn at the DC level, you need at least an OU.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your log, your configuration for ldapsearchattribute="sAMAccountName" doesn't work.

You can use a LDAP tool such as LDAPAdmin or OpenLDAP to test your filter. Make sure that the above return result when your filter the attribute below

```
(sAMAccountName=myUser)
```